# SwitchMe App crashed while switching to new user

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot

I have installed SwitchMe app to use multiple users. When I tried switching to secondary user, the phone rebooted and stuck up on EULA and Diagnostics screen. When clicking next not responding and showing up an error 'Unfortunately Google Play Services Stopped'. I dont know how to boot it to my original user account. I have not took any back up of my data. Please help.